# Extend Report/testng report how can i generate browser specific report

Tags: selenium-extent-report

Currently, I am using selenium grid for run test case parallel on remote pc.And I am using [extend report](http://extentreports.com) for generating a report.Suppose I run the same test case on two different PC with two different browsers.I want to generate the report for two separate browsers on the separate file.

> Using this code I run my automation on the remote computer.

```
@Parameters("browser")
@BeforeMethod
public void launchbrowser(String browser) throws MalformedURLException {


    if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
        System.out.println(" Executing on FireFox");
        String Node = "http://192.168.2.105:5555/wd/hub";
        DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        cap.setBrowserName("firefox");

        wd = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(Node), cap);
        // Puts an Implicit wait, Will wait for 10 seconds before throwing
        // exception
        wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // Launch website
        wd.navigate().to(URL);
        wd.manage().window().maximize();
    }
```

> This code generate my extend report instead of testng reporting.

```
    @BeforeTest
public void setUp() {
    // where we need to generate the report
    String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
    htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("C:/xampp/htdocs/Automation_report/files/alojamento/alojamento("+fileName+").html");

        extent = new ExtentReports();
    extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

    // Set our document title, theme etc..
    htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Alojamiento");
    htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Alojamiento Production Testing");

    htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.TOP);
    htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.DARK);

}
```

> This is the reporting format,Actually i upload it because i want to show why i use this reporting.Use it For GUI

[image]

Can you please suggest me how can i archive my goals?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this case ? I am having same situation and looking for solution,

Comment: @Krishnan Mahadevan Do you have any idea regarding this ?

Answer (score 1):

As per your code, you are launching the browser under **@beforeMethod**. So you need to implement your report under same annotation itself.

```
@Parameters("browser")
@BeforeMethod
public void launchbrowser(String browser) throws MalformedURLException {
Sting fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("C:/xampp/htdocs/Automation_report/files/alojamento/alojamento("+fileName+").html");
        
extent = new ExtentReports();
extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Alojamiento");
htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Alojamiento Production Testing "+browser);
        
htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.TOP);
htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.DARK);
            if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
                System.out.println(" Executing on FireFox");
                String Node = "http://192.168.2.105:5555/wd/hub";
                DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                cap.setBrowserName("firefox");
        
                wd = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(Node), cap);
                // Puts an Implicit wait, Will wait for 10 seconds before throwing
                // exception
                wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        
                // Launch website
                wd.navigate().to(URL);
                wd.manage().window().maximize();
            }
```